# checkbox items that are checked as session name

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Need help. I want to save the items that are check in my checkbox to a Session.

What I'm doing is get the value of the items that are checked and store it in an array. Then I will assign that value as Session Name and assign a value of 1 to the session.

This is the code that I'm using but it only gets the first item that is checked.

```
dim  checkboxList
checkboxList = request.Form("schedule")
checkboxList = split(checkboxList, ",")

for each i in checkboxList
    Session(i) = 1
next
```

for example If I check A and B on my Checkbox I should get

Session("B")=1 and Session("C")=1

but the only thing i'm getting is Session("B")=1

Here is the HTML code i'm using.

```
<div class="controls">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="onShifts" name="schedule" value="onShifts" <% if Session("onShifts") = 1 then response.Write("checked") end if %> /> On Shifts?<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="nightShifts" name="schedule" value="nightShifts" <% if Session("nightShifts") = 1 then response.Write("checked") end if %> /> Night Shifts?<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="partTime" name="schedule" value="partTime" <% if Session("partTime") = 1 then response.Write("checked") end if %> /> Part Time?<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="fullTime" name="schedule" value="fullTime" <% if Session("fullTime") = 1 then response.Write("checked") end if %> /> Full Time<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="holidays" name="schedule" value="holidays" <% if Session("holidays") = 1 then response.Write("checked") end if %> /> Holidays/Sundays?<br>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="projectBasis" name="schedule" value="projectBasis" <% if Session("projectBasis") = 1 then response.Write("checked") end if %> /> Project Basis
                            </div>
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? It doesn't look like that is valid VB.NET code (for instance, you haven't declared a type for "i").

Answer (score 1):

What's the HTML look like? Try

```
for i=0 to uBound(checkboxList)
Session(i) = 1
next
```